# ValueError: No password or public key available

Tags: python, streamlit, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to connect to a remote MySQL database through an SSH Tunnel and deploying my code to Streamlit. When I try to do it, I get this error:

```
File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sshtunnel.py", line 966, in __init__

    (self.ssh_password, self.ssh_pkeys) = self._consolidate_auth(

  File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sshtunnel.py", line 1169, in _consolidate_auth

    raise ValueError('No password or public key available!')

ValueError: No password or public key available!
```

I've tried a lot of things, from updating my SSH keys to my server and github to changing my code.

The code I have for the SSH - MySQL section looks like this:

```
import MySQLdb as db
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

def query(q):

    with SSHTunnelForwarder(                                                  
          ssh_address_or_host=("host_ip"),                         
          ssh_username=("host_username"),                                      
          ssh_pkey=("path_to_private_sshkey"),                                           
          remote_bind_address=("private_host_ip", "host_port")       
     ) as server:
          
          conn = db.connect(
            host="localhost",                          
            port=server.local_bind_port,                                          
            user="db_username",                                              
            passwd="db_password",                                        
            db="db_database"
            )                                           

          return pd.read_sql_query(q, conn)
```

I appreciate any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

```
conn = db.connect(host="localhost"),                      
port=server.local_bind_port,                           
user=("db_username"),            
passwd=("db_password"),     
db=("db_database")
```

Because you have a closing parentheses on the first line, only the `host` argument is being passed to the `db.connect()` function.  And so the function is complaining that it doesn't have a password, username, etc.

The other lines are creating plain local variables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

That's a typo, I'm sorry about that. The correct `db.connect` function does include all those arguments.

Comment: @Cace We can't help unless you update the question with the correct code.

Comment: I'm sorry @John . It should be fixed now. Again, thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm guessing that `ssh_pkey=("path_to_private_sshkey")` is an incorrect filename, and so it can't find it.